# Why does a double free occur?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free, cs50, double-free

I've been trying to write a spell checker program that takes a dictionary and a text file to find the misspelled words as fast as possible. However, I get an error message stating that a double free occurred on running the program. I'd like to know why this happens.

Error message:

```
~/pset5/speller/ $ ./speller texts/constitution.txt

MISSPELLED WORDS

USConstitution
http
usconstitution
const
html
double free or corruption (fasttop)
Aborted
```

Speller (by CS50):

```
// Implements a spell-checker by CS50

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }
    

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

Dictionary operations and checking (by me):

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned long long int N = 50;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char temp_w[LENGTH];
    unsigned int key = hash(word);
    for(node *temp = table[key]; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            temp_w[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->word, temp_w) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)         //Hashed using djb2
{

    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c = *word;
    c = tolower(c);
    while (*word != 0)
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        c = *word++;
        c = tolower(c);

    }

    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char str[LENGTH];
    char counter[1] = "0";
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        //printf("Error: \n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", str) == 1)
    {
        unsigned int key = hash(str);
        //int key = rand();
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(table[key] == NULL)
        {
            table[key] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            table[key]->next = NULL;
            strcpy(table[key]->word, str);
            
        }
        else //if(table[key]->next != NULL)
        {
            temp->next = table[key];
            strcpy(temp->word, str);
            table[key] = temp;
        }
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    long long int words = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        /*if(strcmp(table[i]->word, "0") != 0 && table[i]->next == NULL)
        {
            words++;
            continue;
        }
        else*/
        if(table[i] != NULL)
        {
            for(node *temp = table[i]; temp != NULL; temp = temp -> next)
            {
                words++;
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *temp1 = NULL;
    node *temp2 = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        temp1 = table[i];
        while(temp1 != NULL)
        {
            if(temp1->next != NULL)
            {
                temp2 = temp1 -> next;
                free(temp1);
                temp1 = temp2;
            }
            else free(temp1);
        }
        free(temp2);
        free(table[i]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

`dictionary.h`:

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool check(const char *word);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

Comment: Draw a picture, step through unload on paper. You'll see it. Hint: what are `free(temp2);free(table[i]);` freeing?

Comment: This is not answer "why", but the way to find out. Run the program under gdb, find out where double free occurrs exactly, then analyze code and try to find out how double free can occur in that place. Another way: write your debug_free routine and call it instead of free. Print address in it and place from which it is called, number all invocations with unique number (i.e. like void debug_free(int invocation_id, void* addr) then debug_free(1, p); debug_free(2, p) for the different places). Then by program output find where first and second free of the same address occurrs, try to analyze why.

Comment: @dratenik From the paper diagram, it seems like `free(temp2)` attempts to free memory that was already freed by the `else free(temp1)` line. `free(table[i])` seems to free the memory that `free(temp1)` initially freed. So, I've deleted both lines. Still I get the same error message.

Comment: gcc provides malloc/free tracing: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tracing-malloc.html (or it's easy to roll your own). Then you should be able to find the line number where the alloc happens, along with the line number for the first of the two frees.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for that. I'll try using it.

Comment: One interesting thing would be to see if this is double free reported by free or corruption reported by malloc. You can easily test which one it is by commenting out all the `free`s. If after that you still get the message, it is heap corruption and you should focus on where you could be writing out of bounds.

Comment: The problem seems to occur at the last `free(temp1)`. The penulitmate `free(temp1)` leads to `temp1->next` being `NULL` and `temp1` being a non-null address. However, the last `free(temp1)` causes the double free. If the final `temp1` points to a non-null address, why does freeing it cause an error?

Comment: @user3121023 `LENGTH` is defined as 45. The `word` stored in memory pointed to by `temp1` is `"@\276@", '\000' <repeats 42 times>. So it seems to be out of bounds.

Comment: @user3121023 Changing `LENGTH` to `50` still changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems were present in the code. Tracking the pointers on paper (reco. by dratenik) lead to the removal of:

```
free(temp2);
```

The main problem lay with the fact that freeing a pointer did not automatically set it to `NULL`. This lead to freeing memory that should not have been accessed. It was resolved by replacing:

```
else free(temp1);
```

with:

```
 else 
    {
        free(temp1);
        free(table[i]);
        temp1 = NULL;
    }
```